# HTML - How can i disable auto text correction in my TEXTAREA?

Tags: html, textarea, autocorrect

My textarea contains C# code, so i get red underlines all over the place, is there any way to disable auto correction on a TEXTAREA in html code?

Thank

Answer (score 118, accepted):

I believe you may be looking for `<textarea spellcheck="false"></textarea>`

**Source:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en/controlling_spell_checking_in_html_forms

Comment: thanks, is there a way to add this to my css file? it works if i place it in my html code, but using it with css doesn't seem to work
TEXTAREA.code
{
 spellcheck:false;
}
<textarea class="code">
</textarea>

Comment: This is an HTML5 attribute so can't be handled in a CSS file. It needs to be part of the textarea markup itself. :-)

Comment: If you're using a <textarea> element and want to disable native autocorrect, the correct attribute to set is `spellCheck="false"`

Answer (score 46):

There are two more attributes other than `spellcheck="false"` for iOS (probably Android too) that you might need to add to your text inputs to avoid OS interferer with text content:

- **`autocorrect="off"` for avoiding to complete or suggest a word**
- **`autocapitalize="off"` for avoiding OS transforming `book` to `Book`**
- **`spellcheck="false"` for avoiding OS from highlighting spell errors**

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Try adding the following code to your textarea:

```
 spellcheck="false"
```