# How to change the spellcheck color of the underline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If put some random text in the input text, such as "qwertyui"

```
 <input id="test" type="text">
```

It appears a red curly underline, is it possible to change its color?

Comment: Are you using JQuery SpellChecker?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML - How can i disable auto text correction in my TEXTAREA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496658/html-how-can-i-disable-auto-text-correction-in-my-textarea)

Comment: No, you can't. It is because browser internal spellchecker configuration. Probably, browsers do not let you to change standard color. You may disable spellcheck (HTML5 only) and implement (spellchecker) by yourself with your custom color.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to change spellcheck color in modern browsers. But I've found a CSS selector which doesn't support by any browser. It is `::spelling-error`. The usage like:

```
::spelling-error {
  color: red;
}
```

For more information check [Mozilla  Web Documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::spelling-error)

Answer (score 0):

The ::spelling-error (and also ::grammar-error) CSS pseudo elements allow you to customize the markers drawn by the browser for spelling errors. It is now supported in Chrome and other chromium-based browsers, and should be coming sometime soonish to other browsers.

Whatever properties you define in ::spelling-error completely replace the existing marker. This is because on some platforms the native spelling marker is not amenable to styling.