Android Chrome input listener receives weird data
I have code that intercepts keyboard events like keydown. However I was not able to use it on my Android Phone because keydown event is not working with virtual keyboards on Android Chrome. Because of that I have decided to use input event listener.
Here is how I set input listener:
const tuşaBasılıncaSuniKlavye = (hadise: Event) => {
  const metinHadisesi = hadise as InputEvent;

  let harf = "";
  if (metinHadisesi.data !== null) {
    harf = metinHadisesi.data;
  }

  console.log("Hadise> data: -" + harf + "- -" + harf.slice(-1) + "-");
  console.log("Hadise> inputType: -" + metinHadisesi.inputType + "-");
};

metinSahası.addEventListener("input", tuşaBasılıncaSuniKlavye, false);

Now, if I click keys slowly, everything works fine. However, if I click 1 or 2 keys and then click space 2 times fastly, the listener receives a deleteContentBackward inputType and messes text inside input field up.
An Example:
Hadise> data: -G- -G-
Hadise> inputType: -insertText-

Hadise> data: -h- -h-
Hadise> inputType: -insertText-

Hadise> data: -- --
Hadise> inputType: -deleteContentBackward-

Hadise> data: -Gj - - -
Hadise> inputType: -insertText-

Do you have any idea why this happens? Thanks.

I don't know why my question id being down voted but here is a method I have used to solve this problem for now:
Following the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469824/3517339
I have added these to my input field:
metinSahası.setAttribute("spellcheck", "false");
metinSahası.setAttribute("autocorrect", "off");
metinSahası.setAttribute("autocapitalize", "off");

And for the weird dot and space data like this ". ", I have replaced it with double space. Like this:
harf.replace(". ", "  ")

This is working for now.
